# Listening to keyboard press on a local machine while connected to remote desktop

Tags: python, windows, input, remote-desktop

We have an emulator connected to a pc that emulates "+" press on the keyboard. Because of outsourced company we need to be connected via remote desktop and clicked inside an input box, so when the + is "pressed" it has some functionality in their product (can't change it). I would like to listen for this + presses on our local machine and run a script that listens for this event and when the + is pressed, it sends mqtt message. I have this script created (it is a python script using pynput library + paho-mqtt), however when im clicked inside the remote desktop, the local machine cant see the input, so my script never sees the + pressed. We are using windows remote desktop. I tried to communicate with the outsource company if i can run the script on the remote desktop but they didnt allow it. Is there a way i can achieve simultaneously being clicked inside the remote desktop and also listening for the input on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would have to run the script inside the machine in the virtual environment, as your machine would not be able to identify when the + was pressed, so the ideal would be to run this script in the remote desktop

Comment: As I mentioned, the outsource company didnt allow this approach. The emulator receives signal from a motion sensor that emulates to the +, only solution that i can come up with is adding an IOT device to the sensor, but this is the last resort. Any other idea?

Comment: I dont have ideia, srry, but in last resort you want adding an IOT device